# How to put animation between frames spritesheet in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d .Can any one suggest me a method to give animation for the transition between one frame to another frame.
   this is my code to fetch frames and just display

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"spritesheet.plist"];

```
    // Create a sprite sheet with the Happy Bear images
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"spritesheet.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    // Load up the frames of our animation
    walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <=7; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sprite%d.png", i]]];
    }
    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    // Create a sprite for our bear
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    self.sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprite.png"];
    self.sprite.position=ccp(320,480);
    self.sprite.anchorPoint=ccp(1,1);
    self.walkAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
```

How to do the animation for the transition between frames

thanks in advance

Comment: In the code => CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f]; The delay is used for the transition from one frame to another. Please go through the ray wenderlich tutorial for cocos2d.

Comment: yea we can give the delay but awt abt the animation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want... But to run the animation, just do `[self.sprite runAction:self.walkAction];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not "transition" (morph) between two frames (images), if that's what you mean.

It sounds to me like you want something that's called [keyframe interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame#As_applied_to_motion), which is normally used in 3D animations. A 2D animation displays one frame after another. You can not interpolate between two frames graphically (morphing), you can only interpolate properties like position.